# select multiple case statement return only first case expression value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case, coalesce

Consider my code below; from a long string both numbers and letters should it return only the e-mailadress (the string contains name,phone number, email, etc.).

the raw string could contain both phone number, email etc, and look like the reverse of: 
`[falsefalse070-123456789given-name.surname@gmail.comTrueTrue]`

I want the end result to only display the email-adress, like this:
`[given-name.surname@gmail.com]`

The first case statement removes all the "-" signs embedded in a string of numbers but not those embedded in a string letters (i.e. removes "-" in "070-123456789" but not in "given-name..@gmail.com".

The second case statement removes all the numbers that could exist in the 13 first positions of the string.

If I run the code below, only the first case statement is accounted for. The result is: `"070123456789given-name.surname@gmail.com"`. If I change places on the case statements the result is: `"-given-name.surname@gmail.com"`.

The select statement in the "from"-code selects the phone number and email under the variable [user_account]. It works fine! It´s the first part of the code with the 2 case statements thats is wrong.

How can I write the code so that both case statements works?

```
SELECT COALESCE(
CASE    
    WHEN PATINDEX('%[-]%',C.[user_account]) <= patindex('%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÅÄÖ]%',C.[user_account]) AND PATINDEX('%[-]%',C.[user_account]) > 0
    THEN replace(substring(C.[user_account],PATINDEX('%[-]%',C.[user_account]),1),'-','') + SUBSTRING(C.[user_account],(PATINDEX('%[-]%',C.[user_account])+1),80) 
    ELSE C.[user_account]
END,
CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(C.[user_account],1,13) LIKE '%0%' OR SUBSTRING(C.[user_account],1,13) LIKE '%1%' OR SUBSTRING(C.[user_account],1,13) LIKE '%2%' OR SUBSTRING(C.[user_account],1,13) LIKE '%3%' OR SUBSTRING(C.[user_account],1,13) LIKE '%4%' OR SUBSTRING(C.[user_account],1,13) LIKE '%5%' OR SUBSTRING(C.[user_account],1,13) LIKE '%5%' OR SUBSTRING(C.[user_account],1,13) LIKE '%6%' OR SUBSTRING(C.[user_account],1,13) LIKE '%7%' OR SUBSTRING(C.[user_account],1,13) LIKE '%8%' OR SUBSTRING(C.[user_account],1,13) LIKE '%9%' OR SUBSTRING(C.[user_account],1,13) LIKE '% %'
    THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(C.[user_account],1,13),'0',''),'1',''),'2',''),'3',''),'4',''),'5',''),'6',''),'7',''),'8',''),'9',''),' ','')/*,'-','')*/ + SUBSTRING(C.[user_account],14,80) 
    ELSE C.[user_account]
END)
AS [user_account]


from
(SELECT 
    A.username as unit_id
    ,LEFT(B.string, CHARINDEX('<',B.string)-1) as [Användarnamn]
    ,REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(B.string), CHARINDEX('>', REVERSE(B.string)) -1)) as [user_account]
FROM [statistics].[dbo].[users] A
INNER JOIN (
SELECT  
    [UserId]
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST([PropertyValuesString] as varchar (200)),'False',''),'True',''),'Fals','') as string
FROM [statistics].[dbo].[Profile]) B
ON A.userid=B.userid) C
where unit_id='KN2281'
```

Many thanks in advance,

Cheers!

Comment: Did you try nesting the case?

Comment: After looking at your code, i would rather suggest you to remove COALESCE and try to achieve that E-MAIL formation using a single case statement.

Comment: I think only if you can add some kind of a constant delimiter for email address you cannot split because email can also start as "123@gmail,com".so you cannot actually identify from your present pattern matching.

Comment: @knkarthick24 I get the same result when i just use a single case statement. only the first "when - then" code works. Is there any example in code of how I could write it so it works?